# static variable with multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, static

I have a multithreaded C code, I want to make a global variable to be thread-private. That is each thread has it's own copy of it...what is the best way of doing so?

Comment: You're looking for thread-local storage (aka thread-specific storage). How you get it depends on the compiler, but if you Google for one of those along with the compiler you're using, you should turn up some information (or you could tell us what compiler you're using...)

Comment: curenntly im using gcc but planning to switch to icc...isn't there a compiler independent way?

Comment: for icc use __declspec(thread) to get thread local storage

Comment: and there's no portable way to do it. C doesn't standardise threading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is called [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage). TLS is declared just like any other global (static) variable, but syntax is implementation dependent. For example:

```
// Visual C/C++ and Intel C/C++ on Windows
__declspec(thread) int number;

// GCC and Intel C/C++ on Linux
__thread int number;
```

Boost and TBB have their own portable TLS, but it is C++, not C.

Answer (score 1):

For the Windows NT engine it is possible to pass a pointer to a thread when it is being started. This pointer can point to anything that can be pointed to: in your case a variable.

Personally I prefer to let it point to a member of an indexed structure where every member belongs to a specific thread and contains information pertaining to the thread such as handle, processing statistics etc.

If you go this route remember that each member of the indexed structure should have a size equal to an even multiple of the processor's cache line size (32 or 64 bytes on x86), otherwise the threads will start colliding with each other in the cache when accessing their respective structures. The indexed structure should also begin on an even multiple of the cache line size.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing local variables, not global variables.

It is easily arranged by making the variable an instanced variable using `C` idioms, such as passing a parameter to the thread.